# How to remove \u00e2\u20ac\u2122 from the string when i fetch the string MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

In my table the table column name is description that store the book description, when I fetches the description from database the string Unicode \u00e2\u20ac\u2122 also in my string I want to remove these value from the string. 
Bellow is my php code

```
case 'bookdetails': {
                $query = "SELECT * FROM book";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
                while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $response["Book"]["Id"] = $rows['id'];
                    $response["Book"]["BookName"] = $rows['bookName'];

                    $response["Book"]["Description"] = strip_tags($rows["description"]);
                }
                if($num > 0) {
                    $response["success"] = 1;
                } else {
                    $response["error"] = 1;
                    $response["Error_msg"] = "No record founds.";
                }
                echo json_encode($response);
            break;
            }
```

Output: Description :
Afterwards he would pop them into the tumble drier \u00e2\u20ac\u201c etc....

I want to remove \u00e2\u20ac\u201c these from my output string.

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are Unicode code points. They are probably significant content in your database.

You could try this:

```
  $response["Book"]["Description"] = strip_tags(htmlentities($rows["description"]));
```

But, if you're using the JSON to send this information to a browser, it's very likely the browser will do the right thing.  For example, \u20ac is € and \201c is “ (left double quote). The `htmlentities()` api call will turn the unicode codepoints into their entity equivalent, which makes them slightly easier to read.

```
  \u20ac   &euro;
  \201c    &ldquo;
```

If you prefer to convert the text strings to the 8-bit latin1 (iso8859-1) character set, you can use this kind of clause in your `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT CONVERT(description USING latin1) description,
       CONVERT(title USING latin1) title
```

If you want old-timey 7-bit ASCII, you can do this

```
SELECT CONVERT(description USING ascii) description ...
```

If the codepoints in your data can be represented in the target character set, they'll be converted. Otherwise they'll be substituted with `?` (0x3f), a replacement character.

If you need to search your database contents, that's another question.

Comment: Sir, I want to remove these \u20ac   &euro; etc. Unicode from my string. Thanks for help.

Comment: I explained the MySQL `CONVERT()` function.